# Combining the data in Pandas

Tags: pandas, append

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWAtK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMWJz.png)I am working on a large datasets which include message and reply messages.

I need to combine both column of message and reply to message in a third column. But I am unable to do as I am intended.

My Intended output is follows:-

| S.No | Message | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hello | How are you? |
| 2 | hello | I am good, How are you? |
| 3 | hello | I am fine |
| 4 | hello | You are also fine. |

| S.No | New_Column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | hello |
| 2 | How are you? |
| 3 | I am good, How are you? |
| 4 | I am fine |
| 5 | You are also fine. |

I have used two sets of codes

**First Code**

```
new_column = []
current_message = None

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if current_message is None:
        new_column.append(row['Message'])
        new_column.append(row['Comment'])
        current_message = row['Message']
    else:
        new_column.append(row['Comment'])
        current_message = row['Message']

# Add the first comment as an additional row at the end
new_column.append(df.iloc[0]['Comment'])

# Create a new DataFrame with the new column
new_column_df = pd.DataFrame(new_column, columns=['New_Column'])

# Save the DataFrame to a new CSV file
new_column_df.to_csv('New_Column.csv', index=False)
```

**Second Code**

```
data['comment_text'] = data['comment_text'].fillna('')


# 2. Now, we can apply the operation of merging comment with message text.
# Create a new column by combining 'message' and 'comment_text' only for rows with comments
data['combined'] = data['message'].str.cat(data['comment_text'], sep='\n', na_rep='')

# Display the resulting DataFrame
print(data[['combined']])
```

Both of these codes are not helping to achieve the objectives as I intended to achieve as shown in the picture.

Comment: post the sample dataframe as text so it can be copied and reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

Here [numpy.insert](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) is used to insert the first value `values=df.loc[0, 'Message']` at the beginning. A new dataframe is created. It’s not clear whether you will have other Messages, if so, then you need details on how to determine how to identify the groups Message?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#if you need to filter out empty 'Comment' rows
df = df[df['Comment'].notna()].reset_index(drop=True)

new_column_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'S.No': np.arange(1, len(df) + 2),
        'New_Column': np.insert(df['Comment'], 0,
                                values=df.loc[0, 'Message'])
    }
)


print(new_column_df)
```

Output:

```
   S.No              New_Column
0     1                   hello
1     2            How are you?
2     3  I am good How are you?
3     4               I am fine
4     5      You are also fine.
```

**Update**

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) in the question there is an example of how to create a table that can be easily copied into excel and read in pandas.

Example:

```
| column_name1 | column_name2   |
| --------     | -------------- |
| 1            | 3              |
| 2            | 4              |
```

This is what the table should look like to copy(to reproduce the table simply copy the text from Example):

| column_name1 | column_name2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

After copying, the table is saved to a file with a csv extension. And this way you can read the file by saving it into a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', header=0)

print(df)
```

Or store rows of values separated by commas, with the first row being the column names.

Comment: Hello. Thank you...Its simply amazing.

my earlier provided example was just an illustration of what I wanted to achieve.

However, I have 1 more problem of missing values.

In my dataset, only 10-20% of Messages have the comment. rest of 80-85% of messages do not have a comment.

So, when I apply the above code, it is being applied to the entire data set. It is replacing my message (which does not have the comment) with NaN values. 

So, I need 1 more help in handling missing values in comment column and need something which only address to the rows where we have comment text.

Comment: Added filtering for empty rows 'comment'.

Comment: Thank you very much...I think, there was some key error in 0 but I changed it to values=df.iloc[0]['message'] instead of loc[0]. I hope, my approach will be good. The code is working fine but I need inspect it manually.

Comment: [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) is not an explicit indexing, where line numbers are 0, 1...6,7 and so on. [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is an explicit indexing that uses explicit indexes that you set for example a, b, c, d, e or some dates and so on.
If you do not create indexes, they will be 0.1...6.7 by default. You can view the indexes like this:  print(df.index)

Comment: Thanks for very nice explanation. I think using loc function instead of iloc would be more helpful but how do I handle the key error which is being generated using loc option. 

The orror being generated is key error pointing to the 0

Comment: @Junaid I guess the problem is the following:
When the dataframe is filtered and rows are extracted based on the condition, they retain the original indexes. Since we take the first line, and quite likely it contained an empty Comment line. Therefore there is no row with index 0. To rewrite the indexes, I reset the indexes after filtering **reset_index(drop=True)** --- updated the code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I shall apply this code tomorrow and I shall inform here the outcome. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Hello @inquirer. I am back with another query related to it. This time, I am going to paste a data frame for your kind reference. 

This is kind of sample set of my dataset which I am crunching for my thesis. 

My explicit purpose is to keep an original message and append or insert comments below it.

Comment: I was unable to attach the data file as sample but I have inserted a image which may give you the idea, how my data frame looks like...I have added two images. 

Your help will highly appreciated as I am very new to this stuffs. Thanks Again

Comment: I have added two images in my original post...This will give you the better idea on the way my dataframe looks like. Your help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Junaid I'm busy with something else right now, please create a new question. But it’s better to post the data, pictures are not welcome here.

Comment: @Junaid posted in the update how to make the table so it can be reproduced. I don't have much time to focus solely on pandas. I am now unsuccessfully trying to find a job, and for it I need to know not only pandas, but also many other stacks, which takes time, given that it is not always possible to think calmly.

Comment: Very Great, I wish you all the best in your quest to find your job. Thanks once again